# How to unwrap a JsonObject with a single element and keeping JsonObject's name using Jackson library?

Tags: json, playframework, jackson

In my app I have Serie and each one has 2 fields to represent the texture and .obj file.

```
@Entity
public class Serie extends Model {
    public File obj;
    public File texture;
}
```

And my File class:

```
@Entity
public class File extends Model{
     public String path;
}
```

I would like to generate a Json file to describe my objects. As you can see, the File class has exactly one field. For that reason, I wanna generate a Json without JsonArray to describe my file fields.

Using Jackson library, it generates a json like that:

```
{"obj":{"path":"obj/600s"}, "texture":{"path":"text/600s"}}
```

I would like to generate like that:

```
{"obj":"obj/600s", "texture":"text/600s"}
```

One option that works partly is use the Jackson's annotation @JsonUnwrapped.

```
@Entity
public class Serie extends Model {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    public File obj;

    public File texture;
}
```

Using it the Jackson generate a json like that:

```
    {"path":"obj/600s", "texture":{"path":"text/600s"}}
```

So this does not work for me, because I cannot use for obj, texture fields, and i wanna preserve the fields' names on json.

I know it is a specific question. Any way, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write custom getters to achieve your goal:

```
public class Serie extends Model {
    public File obj;
    public File texture;

    @JsonProperty("obj")
    public String getObjPath() {
        return obj.path;
    }

    @JsonProperty("texture")
    public String getTexturePath() {
        return texture.path;
    }
}
```

/ I assume autodetection is off /

Comment: Thanks man! Worked fine. This is a simple solution. I was thinking about really complex things ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use instead is @JsonValue, but the annotation cannot be set on a field, only on a method (getter):

```
@Entity
public static class File {
    public String path;

    @JsonValue
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
```

}

If serialization is all you need, then this is all you need to do. If you also require deserialization, you will need a single-arg String Constructor or static factory method for json to be able to deserialize your data.

Comment: This not works for me because my class have two fields of same type.

Comment: What do you mean? I tested this with the classes you provided and it works alright...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer)
public class File extends Model{
    public String path;

    // Could be generated by lombok:
    File(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return path;
    }
}
```